# Как получить версию публикации ClickOnce приложения?

Tags: c#, .net, clickonce

Требуется отображать в программе, какая версия опубликованного в ClickOnce приложения сейчас запущена. Просьба не путать с версией сборки приложения.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы получить версию публикации ClickOnce из самого приложения, необходимо сделать три действия:

1. Добавить ссылку в проект на библиотеку [System.Deployment.dll](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.deployment.application(v=vs.110).aspx)
2. Подключить пространство имён:

   ```
   using System.Deployment.Application;
   ```
3. Получить версию установленной публикации:

   ```
   if (ApplicationDeployment.IsNetworkDeployed)
   {
       Version version = ApplicationDeployment.CurrentDeployment.CurrentVersion;
   }
   ```

Comment: А как на .NET ?